# overflow:hidden doesnt work in Firefox?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

```
    /* main content */
#site_content
{ width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

The overflow in function works in all browsers apart from firefox? is there a work around or something i am missing?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What does your HTML look like?

Comment: If you have a look at this link in IE and Firefox you should be able to see...http://www.qservicestesting.co.uk/survey/assessment2.asp?id=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's `#main` which should have the `overflow:hidden`, it's that div which needs to contain the floated logo and site content

alternatively `clear:both` on `#site_content` might also do it.. I didn't look to see what where or why, but `#main` should be the "main" container

PS: also don't know if it's a typo but you have a stray `br` right after the opening `head` tag which is closing it, and making all your styles and scripts go inside the `body` element